# html jquery bar chart plugin unable to make the bars link

Tags: jquery, html, css, bar-chart

Here is a link of a bar chart plugin :

http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Simple-Bar-Chart-Plugin-with-jQuery-Bootstrap-jchart/

But the problem is that I want to make all the bars into links and if user clicks on that it will redirect the user to the given link in that particular bar. But I am not able to do it please help me!
Thanks in advance

Here is the code:

```
<div class="BodyGC">
    <div id="Div1" data-sort="true" data-width="300" class="jChart chart-sm" name="">
    <div class="define-chart-row"  data-color="#009182" title="1">13</div>
    <div class="define-chart-row" data-color="#009182" title="2">24</div>
    <div class="define-chart-row" data-color="#AFCD14" title="3">17</div>
    <div class="define-chart-row" data-color="#AFCD14" title="4">10</div>
    <div class="define-chart-row" data-color="#AFCD14" title="5">12</div>
    <div class="define-chart-row" data-color="#009182" title="6">8</div>
    <div class="define-chart-footer">10</div>
    <div class="define-chart-footer">20</div>
    <div class="define-chart-footer">30</div>   
</div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#Div1").jChart();
    });
</script>
</div>
```

[js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/taditdash/43Zuf)

Comment: "Not able" implies you've tried.  Mind sharing that so that *your* coding problem can be addressed?  Right now, your question is simply asking someone to do it for you.

Comment: i put each div in anchor tag still not working .

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bar Chart plugin - make the each bar clickable (diffrenet link for each )](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24690560/bar-chart-plugin-make-the-each-bar-clickable-diffrenet-link-for-each)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to amend the `bar` variable in `jchart.js` to include an `<a>` tag with a variable `href` attribute. I'm not going to code it for you, because it appears you haven't tried. Have a go with this and come back if you get stuck.

`Bar` variable in the script:

```
var bar = $("<div>", {
    class: "bar",
    "data-placement": "right",
    "data-toggle": "tooltip",
    title: commaSeparateNumber(settings.values[i]),
    style: "height:" + bar_height + "px;background-color:" + settings.colors[i % settings.colors.length],
    width: bar_width
});
```

Comment: i have tried $(".bar").append("<a href="#">Test</a>"); but still not getting anything

Comment: @user3814944 Download the source files. You need to edit `jchart.js` not add a jQuery append. In my answer, you're looking to do something like `var bar = $("<div><a href="' + my_var_url + "', {`. Have a crack at it.

Comment: i have tried to do edit in that but not getting result .

Comment: i am able to show the title but want to redirect on link if user click on any bar ,please help me.