# Bar Chart plugin - make the each bar clickable (diffrenet link for each )

Tags: jquery, html, css, bar-chart

i have used a plugin 
http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Simple-Bar-Chart-Plugin-with-jQuery-Bootstrap-jchart/ 
but the problem is that ,I am not able to make the bars clickable .
My moto is to make each bar link and if user click on that it will redirect user on new link .
but i am not able to do it ,i have tried but able to give only single url for each bar .
Please help me
code on html page :

```
<div id="bar_of_pies" data-sort="true" data-width="300" class="jChart chart-sm" name="">

                    <div class="define-chart-row "  data-color="#dfdfdf"  title="1">13</div>
                    <div class="define-chart-row"  data-color="#F4BE44" title="2">22</div>
                    <div class="define-chart-row"  data-color="#dfdfdf" title="3">20</div>
                    <div class="define-chart-row"  data-color="#F4BE44" title="4">18</div>
                    <div class="define-chart-row"  data-color="#dfdfdf" title="5">16</div>
                    <div class="define-chart-row"  data-color="#F4BE44" title="6">14</div>
                    <div class="define-chart-row"  data-color="#dfdfdf" title="5">12</div>
                    <div class="define-chart-row"  data-color="#F4BE44" title="6">10</div>
                    <div class="define-chart-footer">10</div>
                    <div class="define-chart-footer">20</div>
                    <div class="define-chart-footer">30</div>

                </div>
```

js to active graph :

```
$(document).ready(function () {

                        $("#bar_of_pies").jChart({
                        sort: false,
                        x_label:'Hello',

                        });
                    })
                    });
```

[js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/taditdash/43Zuf/)

Comment: where are giving the url for the bars?

Comment: i have tried to put the div between <a href="#"></a> tag but its not showing after render .
like
<a href="#"><div class="define-chart-row "  data-color="#dfdfdf"  title="1">13</div></a>

Comment: @Anurag have you tried something ?

Comment: i have edited the plugin (jchart.js) but able to redirect on any single url not separate for each

Comment: see the answer provided below. Mark it as answer if you are happy with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have forked your fiddle and updated it here:
http://jsfiddle.net/5ryEZ/5/

**Changes**:
The plugin had to be edited for this to work. I copied the entire plugin into document.ready() and made the changes.

```
<div class="define-chart-row" data-clicker="http://google.com" data-color="#009182" title="1">13</div>
```

Your code for document.ready is present at the bottom.
For urls, add "data-clicker" attribute to the divs.

```
/* replace this code in the jChart.js */
    $.fn.jChart = function (options) {
        var selector = $(this);
        var default_color = "#6b9bd6";
        var bar_height = 19;

        var settings = $.extend({
            width: 750,
            clicker: "http://wditot.in",
            name: null,
            type: "bar",
            headers: null,
            values: null,
            footers: Array(),
            sort: false,
            sort_colors: false,
            colors: Array(),
            x_label: null
        }, options);

        //Initialize some settings that can be set via HTML
        if (settings.name == null) {
            settings.name = $(this).attr("name");
        }
        if ($(this).data("sort") == true) {
            settings.sort = true;
        }
        if ($(this).data("width") != null) {
            settings.width = parseInt($(this).data("width"));
        }
        if ($(this).data("x_label") != null) {
            settings.x_label = $(this).data("x_label");
        }
        if ($(this).data("clicker") != null) {
            settings.clicker = $(this).data("clicker");
        }
        var chart_width = settings.width;
        if ($(this).hasClass("chart-sm")) {
            bar_height = 17;
        } else if ($(this).hasClass("chart-lg")) {
            bar_height = 25;
        } else if (settings.width != null) {
            chart_width = parseInt(settings.width);
        }

        checkForHTMLSettings();

        //Clear the data in the jChart div
        $(this).html("");

        //Create the html containers for the chart
        var chart_title = $("<div>", {
            class: "chart-title",
            html: settings.name
        });
        var legend_left = $("<div>", {
            class: "legend legend-left"
        });
        var x_label = $("<span>", {
            class: "chart-x-label",
            html: settings.x_label
        });

        //Calculate what the chart width should be
        var max_data = Math.max.apply(Math, settings.values);
        var max_footer = Math.max.apply(Math, settings.footers);
        var maxes = [max_data, max_footer];
        var chart_max = Math.max.apply(Math, maxes);
        var container_width = chart_width + 250;

        var chart_container = $("<div>", {
            class: "chart-container",
            width: container_width + "px"
        });
        var chart = $("<div>", {
            class: "chart",
            width: chart_width + "px"
        });
        var legend_bottom = $("<div>", {
            class: "legend-bottom"
        });

        //Place the containers into the target element
        $(this).append(chart_container);
        chart_container.append(chart_title);
        chart_container.append(legend_left);
        chart_container.append(chart);

        //Sort the data if the setting is enabled (Insertion sort)
        if (settings.sort) {
            for (var i = 1; i < settings.values.length; i++) {
                var j = i;
                while (j > 0 && settings.values[j - 1] < settings.values[j]) {
                    var temp = settings.values[j];
                    var head_temp = settings.headers[j];
                    settings.values[j] = settings.values[j - 1];
                    settings.values[j - 1] = temp;

                    //Sort headings
                    settings.headers[j] = settings.headers[j - 1];
                    settings.headers[j - 1] = head_temp;

                    //Sort colors
                    if (settings.sort_colors) {
                        var color_temp = settings.colors[j];
                        settings.colors[j] = settings.colors[j - 1];
                        settings.colors[j - 1] = color_temp;
                    }
                    j--;
                }
            }
        }

        //Loop through headings and create/place them and their corresponding value bars
        for (var i = 0; i < settings.headers.length; i++) {
            var heading = $("<div>", {
                class: "heading heading-left",
                style: "height: " + bar_height + "px;font-size: 10pt;",
                html: settings.headers[i]
            });
            var bar_width = (settings.values[i] / chart_max) * chart_width;
            var bar = $("<div>", {
                class: "bar",
                    "data-placement": "right",
                    "data-toggle": "tooltip",
                title: commaSeparateNumber(settings.values[i]),
                style: "height:" + bar_height + "px;background-color:" + settings.colors[i % settings.colors.length],
                width: bar_width,
                onclick: settings.clicker[i]
            });
            legend_left.append(heading);
            chart.append(bar);
        }
        chart.append(legend_bottom);
        for (var i = 0; i < settings.footers.length; i++) {
            var margin = "margin-left:" + ((settings.footers[i] / chart_max) * chart_width - 9).toString() + "px;";
            var chart_label_bottom = $("<div>", {
                class: "chart-label chart-label-bottom",
                style: margin,
                html: commaSeparateNumber(settings.footers[i])
            });
            var margin = "margin-left:" + ((settings.footers[i] / chart_max) * chart_width - 2).toString() + "px;";
            var chart_label_hr = $("<div>", {
                class: "chart-label-hr",
                style: margin

            });
            legend_bottom.append(chart_label_bottom);
            chart.append(chart_label_hr);
            legend_bottom.append(x_label);
        }

        //Enable hover details
        $(".bar").tooltip();

        return this;

        /**
         * Checks for settings defined in the HTML
         * like chart-define-row and chart-define-footer classes
         */
        function checkForHTMLSettings() {
            //Check for HTML defined bar chart data
            if (selector.find(".define-chart-row").length > 0) {
                settings.headers = Array();
                settings.values = Array();
                settings.clicker = Array();
                selector.find(".define-chart-row").each(function () {
                    settings.headers.push($(this).attr("title"));
                    var value = $(this).html();
                    if (value == null || value == "") {
                        settings.values.push(0);
                    } else {
                        settings.values.push(parseInt(value));
                    }
                    var color = $(this).data("color");
                    var clicker = $(this).data("clicker"); {
                        if (clicker == null || clicker == "") {
                            settings.clicker.push('#');
                        } else {
                            settings.clicker.push(clicker);
                        }

                    }
                    if (color != null) {
                        settings.sort_colors = true;
                        settings.colors.push(color);
                    } else {
                        settings.colors.push(default_color);
                    }
                });
            } else {
                settings.colors.push(default_color);
            }
            //Check for HTML defined footers
            if (selector.find(".define-chart-footer").length > 0) {
                settings.footers = Array();
                selector.find(".define-chart-footer").each(function () {
                    var footer = $(this).html();
                    if (footer != null && footer != "") {
                        settings.footers.push(parseInt(footer));
                    }
                });
            }
        }

        /**
         * Converts a number into a comma separated string
         */
        function commaSeparateNumber(val) {
            while (/(\d+)(\d{3})/.test(val.toString())) {
                val = val.toString().replace(/(\d+)(\d{3})/, '$1' + ',' + '$2');
            }
            return val;
        }


    };

    /* End of code to be copied into jChart.js */
```